# How to get rid of pesky file on macOS

Tags: macos, file, file-permissions

Using macOS 11.2.1

File was created by Migration Assistant directly in Trash @:
~/.Trash/delete/Delete/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/DataVaults

'Empty Trash' throws multiple ‘in use’ errors beginning at ‘Data’ and moving up nested folders

Running First Aid in Recovery Mode does not change anything.  This is what Apple Support Documents recommend.

Yes, I did rename upper 2 folders…
I have assigned ‘Read/Write’ to my user account (which is Admin) to all folders
Finder says ‘You have unknown access’ to ‘DataVaults’

I cannot move any folder out of Trash.

I cannot chown any item in the hierarchy.

The use of ’sudo’ does not alter any results.

How do I get rid of this?
Steve

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested the answer involves SIP:

boot into Recovery Mode

disable SIP (csrutil)

reboot

empty trash

boot into Recovery Mode

enable SIP

reboot